# Issue while displaying a command line in Qterminal

Tags: linux, terminal, archlinux, terminal-emulator

I am currently setting up a linux machine using Arch-based distribution with :

- SDDM as display manager
- LXQT as Desktop environment

Using Qterminal as Terminal emulator, I am encountering the following problem: 
The top part of what I am typing is not showing on display but the entered command still work 
[image: Screenshot]

It seems to be a line spacing problem, nevertheless I am not able to find a workaround for this in settings,
Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for answering

Comment: I don't think you'll find help here. Anyway, this is off-topic here. You may try moving this question to Unix & Linux SE!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's main target stage is Unix & Linux SE!

Comment: Thanks I 'll try Unix & linux SE then